# Change ownership of all objects in a database

Tags: sql-server

I can change the ownership of a single table using `sp_changeobjectowner`.

If I want to change ownership of all the objects in a database, should I write a stored procedure to iterate through each object or is there another way?

UPDATE
I also found that changing the default schema for my user solved the issue that was causing me to think I needed to change ownership of all the objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking to change owners of just tables you can use the undocumented `sp_MSforeachtable` like this:

```
sp_MSforeachtable @command1="sp_changeobjectowner '?', 'new_owner'"
```

If you really need all objects then you'll need to iterate.  One way (but not the only way) would be a cursor like this one:

```
DECLARE @currentObject nvarchar(517)
DECLARE @qualifiedObject nvarchar(517)
DECLARE @currentOwner varchar(50)
DECLARE @newOwner varchar(50)

SET @currentOwner = 'ASPNET'
SET @newOwner = 'dbo'

DECLARE alterOwnerCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT [name] FROM dbo.sysobjects 
WHERE 
  xtype in ('FN','IF','P','TF','U','V', 'TT', 'TF') --Modify list to add and remove object types*
OPEN alterOwnerCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM alterOwnerCursor INTO @currentObject
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   SET @qualifiedObject = CAST(@currentOwner as varchar) + '.' + CAST(@currentObject as varchar)
   EXEC sp_changeobjectowner @qualifiedObject, @newOwner
   FETCH NEXT FROM alterOwnerCursor INTO @currentObject
END
CLOSE alterOwnerCursor
DEALLOCATE alterOwnerCursor
```

Cursor above is an untested and modified version of [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/dneimke/archive/2003/11/10/36691.aspx).

*Note: The cursor query refers to a list of `xtypes`.  Please review [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596.aspx) for the full list.

Comment: I would add to select : **inner join sys.schemas S on S.name = @currentOwner AND sysobjects.schema_id = S.schema_id** in case, not all objects belong to the old owner

Answer (score 5):

Try running this query and then just select all results and execute in separate query

```
select 'EXEC sp_changeobjectowner ''' + S.name + '.' + O.name + '' + ''', ''new_owner'''
from sys.all_objects O
inner join sys.schemas S
on O.schema_id = S.schema_id
where O.type in ('FN','IF','P','TF','U','V', 'TT', 'TF')
```